# Splitting OSM roads and adding additional data

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, openstreetmap

I am using OSM road data as a basis for my project. For some of the roads I have additional info. Pink roads are OSM roads and green is the road data I got elsewhere.
[image]

What I need to do is to find which roads are identical and add the extra info I got to the OSM road layer.

The problem is that the line segments are not the same and the info I want is connected to each of the line segments. Are there any tools that would split the osm line segments so that if the line segment of the other data ends then the OSM segment would also end.

Also are there any tools that compare if the segments are the same? I've been using qgis, gdal, python and postgis for this project.

Comment: Does QGIS have any 'conflation' tools?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you won't be able to do this without some reasonably complex logic. The reason is that your visual "same" is not the same at the underlying (double precision floating point number) data level.

Combining information like this is known as vector conflation, where you have good information in two (or more) sources, but it isn't good in the same way, and you want to get a "best of good" result. One option is [NGA's Hootenanny](https://github.com/ngageoint/hootenanny) - you may also need the [UI git submodule](https://github.com/ngageoint/hootenanny-ui). Its relatively complicated to build the stack, but there are [packages for RPM based distro](https://github.com/ngageoint/hootenanny-rpms) to help along the way.

Answer (score 1):

MAYBE you can get some results via **map matching** ...

see https://graphhopper.com -> Map Matching API

or [Conflation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conflation) according to the OSM wiki.